# Cursor gets stuck at the top and bottom (literally 5 pixels) on my multiple monitor setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

So I have 4 monitors hooked up total. When I move my cursor from any monitor to any other monitor, I cannot do it at the very top or the very bottom. It simply gets stick, like there's a 5-10 pixel edge. My setup looks like this:

[image]

If I move the cursor from #4 to #3 at either of these positions, it will go stuck and I have to move it 5-10 pixels up/down before it goes to the other monitor:

[image]

This is so annoying, because let's say I have my browser maximized on monitor #4 and I try to go to the top of monitor #3, I often move the cursor up there quickly and click to focus the window. Since it gets stuck, I hit X and close my browser. So annoying.

I've tried disabling everything related to Snap and edge support, but none of them worked. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: "I've tried disabling everything related to Snap and edge support" -- what exactly? "Everything" may be "everything you know of". The answer obviously is among the things you don't know. Don't let us miss something you don't know of, that may be an answer but belongs to "everything related to..."

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Search for "snap" in Windows and you will get `Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen`. I've disabled everything in there.